# jQuery autocomplete with dynamically added input field with the same ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

thanks to this script I can create as many input fields (in pair) as i want by clicking an add button. It works correctly. How you can see, for my convenience, all the input fields have the same ID, under the form of [].

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");

        var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"quantita[]\" id=\"quantita[]\" placeholder=\"Dose\" tabindex=\"7\" class=\"field text small\" required>");
        var fType = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"ingrediente[]\" id=\"ingrediente[]\" placeholder=\"Ingrediente\" tabindex=\"7\" class=\"field text medium\" required>");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });

        fieldWrapper.append(fName);
        fieldWrapper.append(fType);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);

        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });
});

</script>
```

Now i would like to activate autocomplete on each of my input texts with family id=ingrediente[]. The values for autocomplete come from a mysql DB and a php file I have prepared works correctly. Here there's the activation script.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#ingredienti[]').autocomplete({
    source:'cerca.php', 
    minLength:2
    });
});
</script>
```

If i try 'cerca.php' on a simple input text in my form it works correctly but, as in the example, i try to use it with ingredienti[] it simply doesn't work.

How could i fix the problem?

Thank you!

**EDIT (AND SOLVED!)**

I added the following code to the script (at the bottom of course).

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("medium");

$(x).autocomplete({
    source:'cerca.php', 
    minLength:2
});
```

Comment: _"all the input fields have the same ID"_ Problem since IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Yeah you need some kind of key to append to your ids.  If you want to select them all at once in jquery, add another class.

Comment: I used the solution with an array because in this way I can have under control the fact that the user could cancel some input texts and so, with the a unique key appended to the ID, I would have some empty random values. Es: ingrediente0, ingrediente1, ingrediente5 (cancelling ingrediente from 2 to 4 with the remove button).

Comment: `[]`'s don't work for ID in javascript like they do for name in php.  Every element should have a unique ID.